# 3-Way Wifi Switch Installation Question

Tags: smart-switch

I'm attempting to install a Kasa Smart 3 Way Switch (HS210).  The installation instructions rely on the outlet box have two neutral (WHITE) wires being currently unused and wire-nutted together in the back of the outlet box.

When I took the plate off my the current switches (both of which control the same lights) this is what I found:

Box 1: There are two cables in this Box.  One cable has a BLACK, WHITE and RED wire.  The RED and WHITE wire go to the switch.  The BLACK wire is under a wire nut with the WHITE wire from the second cable.  The second cable has a WHITE and BLACK wire.  The BLACK wire goes to the switch and the WHITE wire is under a wire nut with the BLACK wire from the first cable.  [Going into the switch is a RED wire (top right), a WHITE wire (top left) a BLACK wire (bottom right) and a ground.  In the back of the outlet box there was a BLACK wire and a WHITE wire, connected together by a wire nut.]

BOX 2:  There is one cable in this box, with BLACK, WHITE and RED wires.
[Going into the light switch is a WHITE wire (top right), a RED wire (top left) a BLACK wire (bottom right) and a ground.  In the box, there is a no other wires.]

Coming off the KASA switch is a GREEN wire (labeled ground), a WHITE wire (labeled neutral) and than three screws: one labeled "load" and the other two labeled "travelers".

As mentioned, the instructions call for the outlet box having two WHITE wires connected together in the back box.  Is there a way to safely install this if I don't have two WHITE wires, but do have a BLACK and WHITE wire connected together?

EDIT:  Thank you for the replies.  Edited to respond to the questions below.  Here is a link to pictures of the boxes:  https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1OibESpeo_cEZXrPeIJdK1yjbl_s7ucUF?usp=sharing

Comment: Unfortunately, switch *positions* don't mean much on 3-way switches - varies by brand and product. What **colors** are the screws on those switches (the "top left", "top right", etc.) - normal choices are black, brass, silver. Also, each of the switch boxes likely has **2 cables** - can you match up (don't move anything, just tell us what you have) the black, white and (for one cable in each box) red - so that we know which wires are "together".

Comment: Can you post photos of the insides of the boxes involved please?

Comment: *Is there a way to safely install this if I don't have two WHITE wires, but do have a BLACK and WHITE wire connected together?* This sounds like "connect to the neutral bundle" - that may or may not actually be necessary. **However, black and white together are definitely NOT neutrals!** White in a cable can sometimes be hot, and that is quite likely the case here. But black can never (except really large sizes, not applicable here) be neutral.

Comment: There is a way to configure an old (not smart) three way switch where one of the switches is on a switch loop and does not have a neutral available.   Black connected to white is a sign you might have this configuration.  It would help if you identified which wires come from which cables where there is more than one cable entering a box, and also the color of the screws they are connected to on the old switch.

Comment: Switch positions don't help, they differ on every switch.  Please go to the browser you posted your question on, and [edit] your question to tell us "how wires are grouped into cables" and 3-way screw colors.  In fact, the 2 brass 3-way screws are for *travelers*, so feel free to just say something like "black and red from cable 1 are travelers".

Comment: from the count of cable-ends  it's failrly clear that these two switches are on a switrch loop with no neutral.

Answer (score 1):

Box #2 is the "far end" of your multi-way switch. The only wire is your 3-line cable with your hot (black) and two travelers (white and red).

Box #1 has the other end of this... but the problem is your other cable only has two wires. The white wire is being used as the incoming hot, as evidenced by

> In the back of the outlet box there was a BLACK wire and a WHITE wire, connected together by a wire nut.

The black wire it's nutted to goes to the common screw of your "far" switch. So, you don't have a neutral in your setup. Your only real solution here would be to replace that wire coming from your fixture with a three-line cable (14/3 in this case). It would involve

- Connect the new black wire where the existing 2-line white is for your incoming hot
- Connect the red to where the existing 2-line black is for your incoming hot
- Connect the white to the neutral at your fixture

The only other alternative would be to buy a switch that does not require a neutral.

Comment: Thank you! Based on what you wrote, I think I will get this (https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B082LKCXV9/) which says no neutral is required.  Thanks again.